# Last ImageButton Not Working

Tags: android

The last ImageButton doesn't work, when I swap the last ImageButton with the second last ImageButton it works but the last one doesn't work now, so I am sure my buttons are registering correctly except for the last one, anytime I swap them around the last one always doesn't work, I have no hidden layouts or anything of a sort:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    >
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Choose your option(s) below:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:textStyle="italic"
        />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibSingle"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/radio_empty" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSingle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Single"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        />

</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibSeeking"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/radio_empty" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSeeking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Seeking"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibDrinking"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/radio_empty" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDrinking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Drinking"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibSmoking"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/radio_empty" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSmoking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Smoking"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        />
</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Notice the 'Smoking' ImageButton is the last one, if I swap it with 'Drinking' for example then Smoking works and drinking doesn't work

JAVA:

```
    ibSingle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibSingle);
    ibSeeking = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibSeeking);
    ibDrinking = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibDrinking);
    ibSmoking = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibSmoking);

    sendSingle = "0";
    sendSeeking = "0";
    sendDrinking = "0";
    sendSmoking = "0";

    ibSingle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             if (sendSingle.equals("0"))
             {
                 ibSingle.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_fill);
                 sendSingle = "1";
             }
             else if (sendSingle.equals("1"))
             {
                 ibSingle.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_empty);
                 sendSingle = "0";
             }
        }
    });

    ibSeeking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             if (sendSeeking.equals("0"))
             {
                 ibSeeking.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_fill);
                 sendSeeking = "1";
             }
             else if (sendSeeking.equals("1"))
             {
                 ibSeeking.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_empty);
                 sendSeeking = "0";
             }
        }
    });
    ibDrinking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             if (sendDrinking.equals("0"))
             {
                 ibDrinking.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_fill);
                 sendDrinking = "1";
             }
             else if (sendDrinking.equals("1"))
             {
                 ibDrinking.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_empty);
                 sendDrinking = "0";
             }
        }
    });
    ibSmoking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             if (ibSmoking.equals("0"))
             {

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "last-button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 ibSmoking.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_fill);
                 sendSmoking = "1";
             }
             else if (sendSmoking.equals("1"))
             {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "last-button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 ibSmoking.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_empty);
                 sendSmoking = "0";
             }
        }
    });
```

And yes I prefer to code my own manual radio or checkbox buttons and not use the the built in method.

Everything works as expected except the last ImageButton (whichever one is placed last), it makes a click sound only. I tried to add a firth dummy ImageButton now the last 2 ImageButtons ('Dummy' and 'Smoking') didn't work, if it did then I would make 'Dummy' invisible but too bad that hack didn't work.

Comment: shouldn't it be 'if (sendSmoking.equals("0"))' instead of if '(ibSmoking.equals("0"))' ?

Comment: @Prexx thanks my mistake, late night coding made me miss that, thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

Please check you if condition in are you use  if (**ibSmoking**.equals("0")) replace **ibSmoking** to **sendSmoking**.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fault in this line  `if (ibSmoking.equals("0"))` in `ibSmoking` clickListener. You check wrong condition in this line.

Answer (score 0):

The main Problem is in your condition if(ibSmoking.equals("0")).
You are checking the condition with imagebutton name rather than String value.
Replace this condition with if(sendSmoking.equals("0")).